# Plot NA counts in a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question related to the histograms in R using ggplot2. I have been working trying to represent some values in a histogram from two different variables. After trying and looking for some solutions in Stackoverflow I got it but...does somebody know how to print NAs count as a new column just to compare the missings in the two variables?

Here is the R code:

```
i<-"ADL_1_bathing"
j<-"ADL_1_T2_bathing"

t1<-data.frame(datosMedicos[,i])
colnames(t1)<-"datos"
t2<-data.frame(datosMedicos[,j])
colnames(t2)<-"datos"
t1$time<-"t1"
t2$time<-"t2"

juntarParaGrafico<-rbind(t1,t2)

ggplot(juntarParaGrafico, aes(datos, fill = time) ) + 
  geom_histogram(col="darkblue",alpha = 0.5, aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = 0.2, position = 'dodge', na.rm = F) + 
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position=c(1, 1))+
  labs(title=paste0("Distribution of ",i), x=i, y="Count")
```

And this is the output:

Image about the two variables values but without the missing bars:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to summarise the number of NAs b4 plotting. How about this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(1:20))
df1[sample(1:20, 5),] = NA
df2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(1:20)) 
df2[sample(1:20, 3),] = NA
df2$time = "t2"
df1$time = "t1"
df = rbind(df1, df2)
df %>% group_by(time) %>% summarise(numNAs = sum(is.na(a)))
histogramDF= df %>% group_by(time) %>% summarise(numNAs = sum(is.na(a)))

qplot(x=time, y = numNAs, fill=time, data = histogramDF, stat='identity',     geom="histogram")
```